# Understanding iptables output for filtering packets

Tags: iptables

I am working on one sles12 system where IPTables are configured in this way:

```
num  target     prot opt source               destination
1    ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:bctp owner UID match dd-test-user
2    DROP       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:bctp
3    DROP       all  --  anywhere             instance-data.us-west-2.compute.internal  owner GID match test
4    ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             ip-100-34-0-0.us-west-2.compute.internal/21  owner GID match test
```

Can someone please help me understand this?
With IPTable rule 2, All packets will be dropped?
What does dpt:bctp mean here? I could not find anything about it manual.
Does Rule 4 even get chance to be applied for the process running from group id of "test" group?

I tried searching online documentation of iptables, but I could not find answer.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because From the iptables tag: IPTABLES SUPPORT IS OFF-TOPIC. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Support questions may be asked on https://superuser.com. Use this tag only for questions on programming with iptables. Questions about configuring iptables should be asked on Server Fault (https://serverfault.com/). Please delete this.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that bctp stands for one of the protocol defined on the system

```
 cat /etc/services | grep bctp
bctp               8999/tcp     # Brodos Crypto Trade Protocol  [Alexander_Sahler]
bctp               8999/udp     # Brodos Crypto Trade Protocol  [Alexander_Sahler]
```

Rule 2 is applied when destination port (dpt) is this protocol (8999/tcp). Rule 3 and 4 are applied for rest of ports from the process belonging to users from the group  "test".